# Excel: Is it possible to find the average of each corresponding industry without having to do it individually?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have two columns of data, one displaying the company's industry and the other displaying revenue growth. I need a third column where the industry average revenue growth is shown. Is there any way I can reconcile the text in the industry row with the values in the growth to compute and drag the industry average?

Comment: have you tried averageif() or averageifs() ?

Comment: you could also use a pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

[image]

**Formula that I used in F3 and F4:**
`=AVERAGEIF(A1:B17;E3;B1:B17)`

First argument is Your range: the 2 columns that You have.

Second is the criteria: in my case its column E.

Third is the range where it calculates the average from: in my case its column B.

Comment: The use of unique() and a dropdown list to pick the company would be a good addition by the OP. plus 1 though.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you wanted to ***ignore*** errors in the `Growth` column. If that is not the case, please clarify.

Using a **Table** with structured referencing, if you have Office 365 with the `FILTER` function, you can use:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER([Growth],NOT(ISERR([Growth]))*([@Industry]=[Industry])))
```

Enter it in the first row of the `avg per industry` column and it will automatically fill down to the bottom of the table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Import this formula to D column:

`=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$A$1:A"&ROW()),A1)=1,AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$13,A1,$B$1:$B$13),"")`

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Long shot when using Office 365:
`=LET(x,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),y,UNIQUE(x),IF(SEQUENCE(1,2)<=COLUMNS(x),y,AVERAGEIF(A:A,INDEX(y,SEQUENCE(3)),B:B)))`

It'll spill the unique names in column A and it's average behind it in one go.

[image]